# Usage of Spring options tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to know what does the `options tag` do in Spring's form namespace. I don't understand how itemValue attribute related to map key as mentioned in the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-optionstag). 
Say for instance I have following method in controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("rights")
public Map<ADMIN_RIGHTS, String> populateRights(){
    Map<ADMIN_RIGHTS, String> rights = new LinkedHashMap<ADMIN_RIGHTS, String>();
    rights.put(ADMIN_RIGHTS.ADMIN, "administrator");
    rights.put(ADMIN_RIGHTS.COMP,"company");
    rights.put(ADMIN_RIGHTS.EMP,"Employee");

    return rights;
}
```

The jsp is:

```
 <form:select path="right" >
     <form:options items="${rights}"/>
 </form:select>
```

And the propertyEditor class is:

```
public class RightsPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

@Override
public String getAsText() {
    Right right = (Right) getValue();
    if (right != null) {
        return right.getName();
    }
    return super.getAsText();
}

@Override
public void setAsText(String rightStr) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (rightStr != null && rightStr.equals("ADMIN")){
        rightStr = "Adminstrator credential";
    }
    else if(rightStr != null && rightStr.equals("COMP")){
        rightStr = "Computer credential";

    }
    else if(rightStr != null && rightStr.equals("EMP")){
        rightStr = "Employee credential";

    }
    setValue(new Right(rightStr));
}
```

In the jsp I don't give the itemValue and itemLabel but still everything works. So what is it I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked to says:

> Alternatively, you may specify a Map of items, in which case the map
>   keys are interpreted as option values and the map values correspond to
>   option labels.

So, the tag displays the keys of the map as values, and its values as labels, as documented.

Answer (score 0):

By default for a map, options value is the `map key` and the label is the `map value`, the `map value` being a Right object the property editor would kick in to display the `right name`. If the property editor is not available, say for the key, then it would use `toString()` to display the value.